# Swift HTTP Request Completion Block not Working Properly

Tags: swift, xcode

I have a weird problem with HTTP requests in Swift. I have the following simple code:

```
let session = URLSession.shared
let url = URL(string: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")!

let task = session.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: { data, response, error in
    // Check the response
            print(error)
            print(response)
})
task.resume()
```

Running this code in a Xcode playground outputs the print statements. However, executing it in a standard Xcode project does not give any output.
I wonder if I am missing something in my code or if something is wrong with my Xcode setup.

Thanks in advance!

Edit:

Here's a screenshot of Xcode
[image]

Comment: Can you share where in Xcode project (NOT in a Playground) are you running/calling it from?

Comment: I guess the problem is that task.resume() is executed in another thread. However, the main thread finishes before any outputs from the other thread can be posted

Comment: What is your definition of the thing that you so-call Completion Block?  What is the guy named 'completionHandler' for?

Comment: The completionHandler is the closure at the end of the dataTask method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Tarun indicated, your executable is exiting before your call can be made. One way you can wait before exiting is to use a `DispatchGroup` like the following.

```
let session = URLSession.shared
let url = URL(string: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")!
let group = DispatchGroup()
group.enter()
let task = session.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: { data, response, error in
    // Check the response
    print(error)
    print(response)
    group.leave()
})
task.resume()
group.wait()
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this screenshot -
[image]

It doesn't seem like any part of your code is executing at all. There's no **entry point** defined.

You can try following -

```
@main
struct NewApp {
    static func main() {
        // Paste all of your code here
        // Put breakpoints and inspect what you want
    }
}
```

Comment: The code is executed. Placing a simple print statement after task.resume() is outputted to the console. However, the completionHandler isn’t

Comment: Now that's a different story, what's happening now is - your program's not waiting long enough for the call to be completed (asynchronously). You can try all this code in an empty iOS template project without such issues since app life time is as long as you want to keep it open. In this case your program exits before the API call has had a chance to complete.

Comment: Yeah, that’s what I meant in the comment above. I guess I would need to somehow either make the main thread wait. Coming from Python, I would kind of connect the task.resume() thread to the main thread. However, since I’m quite new to Swift I need to figure out how to do this first